# Is it possible to send a transaction from a 0 balance EOA through a funded Smart Contract, such as the latter pays the tx fees?

Tags: fees, meta-transactions

I think there is something similar called Meta-transactions, but my understanding is that those are EOA to EOA. I'm more interested in being able to send a transaction from a EOA with zero balance that calls a function from a Smart Contract with a `balance > 0`, such as the Smart Contract is the one paying the fees (or what is the same: the fees are payed from the Smart Contract's balance instead of the EOA balance).

Is this doable somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think smart contract pay fees. Because if they pay fees, someone can drain the smart contract wallet very easily. He can just ask multiple small transactions from the contract.